# How to iterate a C# class look for all instances of a specific type, then calling a method on each instance

Tags: c#, reflection, methods, field

Is it possible (via reflection?) to iterate all fields of an object calling a method on each one.

I have a class like so:

```
public class Overlay
{
    public Control control1;
    public Control control2;
}
```

I'd like a method that goes something like this:

```
public void DrawAll()
{
    Controls[] controls = "All instances of Control"
    foreach (Control control in Controls)
    {
        control.Draw()
    }    
}
```

Can this be done?  I've been able to get all the metadata on the Control class but this relates only to the type not the specific instance.

I know this seems odd but I have my reasons.  I'm using Unity 3D and each control is actually a GUI control instantiated by the editor.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I'd like the method DrawAll() to be within the same class the the Control instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Overlay overlay = new Overlay();
        foreach (FieldInfo field in overlay.GetType().GetFields())
        {
            if(typeof(Control).IsAssignableFrom(field.FieldType))
            {
                Control c = field.GetValue(overlay) as Control;
                if(c != null)
                    c.Draw();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This will filter out fields in the class that aren't controls. Also, [IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) will return true for any field types that inherit from Control, assuming you wish to handle these fields as well.

Comment: That works for me. I'll mark this as the answer due to the additional IsAssignableFrom info.  I'll actually be using this to iterate all instances derived from a specific base class so this also answers my other issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
var props = typeof(Overlay).GetProperties().OfType<Control>();
```

Comment: +1 Believe you can even shorten that to `typeof(Overlay).GetProperties().OfType(typeof(Control));`

Comment: @pickypg: good point, I'm half asleep, though it's OfType<Control>()

Comment: That's what I get for typing from memory :). Not so sleepy after all! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Overlay obj = new Overlay();
Type t = typeof(Overlay);
FieldInfo[] fields = t.GetFields();
foreach (FieldInfo info in fields)
{
    Control c = (Control)info.GetValue(obj);
    c.Draw();
}
```

Note, that you need to add additional check of type of returned value by `GetValue()` if your object has also not `Control` fields.