# How to iterate a C# object, looking for all instances of a specific type, in order to build a separate list of those instances?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, enumeration

I have a need that is a bit similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146640/how-to-iterate-a-c-sharp-class-look-for-all-instances-of-a-specific-type-then-c), except that it requires a deeper exploration of the source object.

Here is a code sample:

```
public class Target {};

public class Analyzed
{
    public Target EasyOne { get; set; }
    public IList<Target> ABitMoreTricky { get; set; }
    public IList<Tuple<string, Target>> Nightmare { get; set; }
}
```

From an instance of `Analyzed`, I want to extract all the `Target` instances.

In order to ease the exploration, we can assume the following:

1. Explore only properties.
2. There is no infinite reference loop.

For now, `EasyOne` is... easy, but I am looking for some strategy to get all the `Target` instances lost in more tricky structures.

Comment: Generic parameters themselves do not have _instances_.

Comment: To @M.Babcock's point- I assume you meant the instance of Target stored in each of the Tuples stored in the IList `Nightmare`?

Comment: I don't understand, whats the question with your example.

Comment: Make the class serializable, serialize it into a xml, extract the Target nodes, deserialize them. It's a joke :P

Comment: @M.Babcock, Chris Shain gave you the right answer.

Comment: @BlueM, again Chris Shain gave a good explanation.

Comment: @Chris Shain, thanks for clearing out my question :)

Comment: @remio - Chris Shain was clarifying my brief (yet correct) comment. I didn't ask a question so there was nothing for him to answer.

Comment: @Adrian Iftode, I liked a lot your solution too :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about something along these lines:

```
    public List<T> FindAllInstances<T>(object value) where T : class
    {

        HashSet<object> exploredObjects = new HashSet<object>();
        List<T> found = new List<T>();

        FindAllInstances(value, exploredObjects, found);

        return found;
    }

    private void FindAllInstances<T>(object value, HashSet<object> exploredObjects, List<T> found) where T : class
    {
        if (value == null)
            return;

        if (exploredObjects.Contains(value))
            return;

        exploredObjects.Add(value);

        IEnumerable enumerable = value as IEnumerable;

        if (enumerable != null)
        {
            foreach(object item in enumerable)
            {
                FindAllInstances<T>(item, exploredObjects, found);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            T possibleMatch = value as T;

            if (possibleMatch != null)
            {
                found.Add(possibleMatch);
            }

            Type type = value.GetType();

            PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetProperty);

            foreach(PropertyInfo property in properties)
            {
                object propertyValue = property.GetValue(value, null);

                FindAllInstances<T>(propertyValue, exploredObjects, found);
            }

        }

    private void TestIt()
    {
        Analyzed analyzed = new Analyzed()
        {
            EasyOne = new Target(),
            ABitMoreTricky = new List<Target>() { new Target() },
            Nightmare = new List<Tuple<string, Target>>() { new Tuple<string, Target>("", new Target()) }
        };

        List<Target> found = FindAllInstances<Target>(analyzed);

        MessageBox.Show(found.Count.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, RQDQ, this answers perfectly my question. I was not expecting so much... You even managed the infinite reference loop.

Comment: The line `object propertyValue = property.GetValue(value, null);` fails if you have an indexed property (this[int index]), easy to check, but then you're skipping stuff. I rewrote it to use FieldInfo which is just as easy as properties.

Comment: Hi @Jaap , would you mind explaining "I rewrote it to use FieldInfo"? Cheers.

Comment: I used the fields instead of properties. In some automatic serialization scenarios fields are more appropriate (lots of downsides too of course). Instead op type.GetProperties, at the time type.GetFields worked fine then.

Comment: Recommended refinement: I've used similar code to iterate over all objects, and I found testing for IEnumerable was prone to finding stored Linq queries and clobbering them, or other objects designed to dump runtime-created enumerable data. I suggest changing IEnumerable references to ICollection, which should generally be safe to iterate over; I've never encountered a situation where ICollection works worse than IEnumerable :)

Comment: Also `string` implements IEnumerable. Should skip strings

Answer (score 1):

You could go the reflection way, and have special treatment for all the containers you know (IEnumerable, IDictionary, all Tuples, and who knows what else), *or* you can actually implement what @Adrian Iftode jokingly said in a comment.

I don't think you really want to serialize to XML and then parse it. It will work, but it will require all your objects to be XML serializable, which, if I am not mistaken, requires all serialized data to be public.

You should use the ordinary serialization, but define your own custom formatter that does nothing but track the objects you're looking for. Here's an example of a [simple custom formatter.](http://geekswithblogs.net/luskan/archive/2007/07/16/113956.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using reflection. There are two tasks to solve:

1. Get all properties of a type. `Type.GetProperties()` will do that.
2. Determine if a property type is of type `Target` or is generic type with `Target` as a type argument. You can use `Type.IsGenericType` to test if a type is generic and `Type.GetGenericArguments` to get the actual type arguments. If a match is found you should recurse this generic type starting at 1 and perform the match described in 2.

So by using reflection and recursion on generic types should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> Dim tTargets() = {New List(Of Target) From {New Target("Joe"), New
>   Target("Bob")}, New Target("Veronica"), New Tuple(Of String, Target,
>   DateTime, Target)("A Tuple", New Target("Henry"), DateTime.Now, New
>   Target("Deacon"))}

```
Sub ShowMeTheTargets(ByVal tRoot As Object, ByVal tLevel As Int32)

        Dim tCount As Int64 = 0
        Dim tCountName As String = "Length"

        If Nothing Is tRoot Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If tRoot.GetType Is GetType(Target) Then
            RTB.AppendText("Found: " & CType(tRoot, Target).Name & vbCrLf)
            '
            '   Assume Target is not a Target container.
            '
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If LEVEL_MAX = tLevel Then
            '
            '   We don't want to scan this object graph any deeper
            '
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If (Nothing Is tRoot.GetType.GetInterface("IEnumerable")) Then
            For Each tProperty As PropertyInfo In tRoot.GetType.GetProperties
                ShowMeTheTargets(tProperty.GetValue(tRoot, Nothing), tLevel + 1)
            Next
        Else
            For Each tObject As Object In tRoot
                ShowMeTheTargets(tObject, tLevel + 1)
            Next
            RTB.AppendText(tCount & vbCrLf)
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Boo. It looks like RQDQ's (even if I am not really used to read VB).

Comment: Yeah, RQDQ beat me to it.. but since I did the work I posted it anyhow.